Downsampling with terra to arbitrary grids, resample() and project() only subset
I want to downsample model output to a coarser, arbitrary new grid.
aggregate() does not do the trick, as I want to arrive at a specific grid.
For some reason, resample() and project() only return a "zoomed" subset and not the desired product: the aggregated/downsampled data on a new grid.
I feel that the solution must be very obvious, but i could not find anything on stackoverflow/rseek at all.
Here is some example code:
library(terra)
# dummy starting raster
raw <- rast(ext(c(-0.5625, 359.4375, -89.70215791342, 89.70215791342)),nrow=160,ncol=320)
# with some "structure" to see the changes
values(raw) <- (1:ncell(raw))/10000+c(rep(1,ncell(raw)/4),rep(2,ncell(raw)/4),rep(1,ncell(raw)/4),rep(2,ncell(raw)/4))
# correct specs:
raw
plot(raw)

#desired new projection(?)
newgrid <- rast(xmin=1,xmax=128,ymin=1,ymax=64,nrow=64,ncol=128)#,crs="wgs84"

#modify with resample or project
new1 <- project(raw,newgrid,method="bilinear")
new2 <- resample(raw,newgrid,method="bilinear")

#that created only a subset/"zoom" and not a new map with different grid
plot(new1)
plot(new2)

I tried aggregate, resample and project functions of terra package in different variants. I want to transform my starting rast to a new one with the desired extent, resolution, etc.
Aggregation does not work, because I want to have a specific grid; resample and project return only a subset instead of the full set of values on the new grid.
sessioninfo:


'zoomed subset' is akin to crop, as these two rast don't align very well but have some overlap, the zoomed part.

the mission is not to zoom, but to resample the raw values onto a new grid, that happens to be x=1:128, y=1:64; i tried to clarify the question,

As @Chris noted, the extent of newgrid is smaller than that of raw, so only the overlapping areas will be resampled(). Note that even though terra::rast() has assigned WGS84/EPSG:4326 to your SpatRasters by default, it is good practice to do it explicitly.
To illustrate the issue:
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

# dummy starting raster
raw <- rast(ext(c(-0.5625, 359.4375, -89.70215791342, 89.70215791342)), 
            nrow = 160,
            ncol = 320,
            crs = "EPSG:4326")

values(raw) <- (1:ncell(raw))/10000 + c(rep(1,ncell(raw)/4),rep(2,ncell(raw)/4),
                                        rep(1,ncell(raw)/4),rep(2,ncell(raw)/4))


newgrid <- rast(ext(1, 128, 1, 64),
                nrow = 64,
                ncol = 128,
                crs = crs(raw))

new <- resample(raw, newgrid, method = "bilinear")

# For illustrative purposes
v1 <- vect(ext(raw), crs = "EPSG:4326")
v2 <- vect(ext(newgrid), crs = "EPSG:4326")

ggplot() +
  geom_spatvector(data = v1,
                  aes(colour = "raw\nextent")) +
  geom_spatraster(data = new) +
  geom_spatvector(data = v2,
                  aes(colour = "newgrid\nextent"),
                  lwd = 1,
                  fill = NA) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "", values = c("firebrick", "black")) +
  theme_void()


One way to ensure your resampled Spatraster retains its original extent:
# Create new Spatraster with lower resolution, same extent as raw
newgrid <- rast(ext(raw), nrow = 64, ncol = 128, crs = "EPSG:4326")

# Resample raw using newgrid
new <- resample(raw, newgrid, method = "bilinear")

raw
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 160, 320, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 1.125, 1.121277  (x, y)
# extent      : -0.5625, 359.4375, -89.70216, 89.70216  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source(s)   : memory
# name        :  lyr.1 
# min value   : 1.0001 
# max value   : 7.1200 

new
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 64, 128, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 2.8125, 2.803192  (x, y)
# extent      : -0.5625, 359.4375, -89.70216, 89.70216  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source(s)   : memory
# name        :    lyr.1 
# min value   : 1.032195 
# max value   : 7.087905

